# Problem using on_the_spot gem with rails 3 and newly created records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using the on_the_spot gem for editing a certain column in a rendered table. This works fine.
But when I create a new records and update the table using AJAX I get the following error message:

"ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"update_attribute_on_the_spot", :controller=>"stores_spare_parts"}): "

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How do you create the new records? Are they saved in the database? Because it seems you are missing the `:id` in the route. Could you please show the code for the view? I imagine that after creation of the item through Ajax, you would re-render part of the view with the data from the database (including the ID).

Comment: New records are being saved to the database, here is the controller code for the action:

https://gist.github.com/946326

Comment: How does your `create.js`-view look?

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly: in the index-view it works, if you create a new element, and you update your table, inside the index-view using ajax, then it no longer works, correct?

Comment: And here is the view: https://gist.github.com/946385

Comment: Here is the create.js: https://gist.github.com/946387

Comment: nathanvda: yes, thats correct

Comment: Mmmmm i do not see a `on_the_spot_edit` in your code?

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I pasted the wrong partial. Here is the correct one: https://gist.github.com/946385

Answer (score 0):

From the code i see no obvious error. What i guess that is wrong is that the mentioned route is indeed not defined. I would assume that was not possible, because it works in the `index`-view, but if the index-view belongs to a different controller, e.g. the store, and creating the `store_spare_part` goes to his controller, than that is a possible solution. But this is just a guess.

So do you have the following in your routes:

```
resources :stores_spare_parts do
  collection do
    post :update_attribute_on_the_spot
  end
end
```

With the information i have now, this is the only logical explanation i can think of. I hope it helps.

[EDIT: found another workaround] I forgot, but the `on_the_spot` gem has the option to explicitly specify the `url`. The intention was to be able to supply/use your own method, but it could also be used in this case.

Usage:

```
on_the_spot_edit post, :title, :url => url_for({:controller => 'stores/store_spare_parts', :action => :update_attribute_on_the_spot})
```

It still remains weird that it should be needed, but I hope this is a valid workaround.

Comment: Then add it as a non-nested route. For the nested route the url-hash would look like this: `{:action=>"update_attribute_on_the_spot", :controller=>"stores/stores_spare_parts"}`.

Comment: Probably stupid, but you did restart the rails application? Otherwise can you show the `routes.rb` ?

Comment: I Barriere the Error down a Little further. The Problem seems to Be, that the method 'url_for' Works in my Index method but not in the create method. I'll create a new Question for this problem and post the link here.

Comment: Ok @daniel, Good luck. If you would write an explicit url: `on_the_spot_edit post, :title, :url => '/stores/store_spare_parts/update_attribute_on_the_spot'`, doesn't that work? If not: what url does that generate then?

Comment: I have had a similar problem, when dynamically adding routes. Do you do any of that? In rails2 you could easily add stuff to the routing, in rails3 that effectively wipes the whole routing and only the newly "added" stuff remains.

Comment: No, as far as I'm aware of it I'm not doing anything to my routes.

Comment: Here is the link to the new question concerning the routing problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856094/rails-3-routing-error-only-in-a-certain-method