# Rails 3: Routing error only in a certain method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am experiencing a strange behavior for a certain record in my routes.rb. Here is an excerpt of my routes.rb:

```
resources :stores do
  resources :stores_spare_parts do
    collection do
      post :update_attribute_on_the_spot
    end
  end
end
```

When I now call the method `url_for` in my index action of the stores_spare_parts Controller, it returns `http://127.0.0.1:3000/stores/1/stores_spare_parts/update_attribute_on_the_spot`. But when I do the same in my create action it stops working with the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError
(No route matches  {:action=>"update_attribute_on_the_spot",
:controller=>"stores_spare_parts"}):
app/controllers/stores_spare_parts_controller.rb:19:in `block in create'
app/controllers/stores_spare_parts_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

Here is the controller code for the index and the create method:

```
def index
  Rails.logger.debug { "---------------------------" }
  Rails.logger.debug { url_for(:action => 'update_attribute_on_the_spot') }
  Rails.logger.debug { "---------------------------" }

  @currentStore = Store.find(params[:store_id])
  @activeStores = Store.scoped_by_deactivated(false)
  @storesSpareParts = StoresSparePart.scoped_by_store_id(@currentStore.id)
end

def create
  Rails.logger.debug { "---------------------------" }
  Rails.logger.debug { url_for(:action => 'update_attribute_on_the_spot') }
  Rails.logger.debug { "---------------------------" }

  return

  @newStoreSparePart = StoresSparePart.new(params[:stores_spare_part])

  if @newStoreSparePart.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated spare part for store #{@newStoreSparePart.store.title}."
    @currentStore = @newStoreSparePart.store
    @activeStores = Store.scoped_by_deactivated(false)
    @storesSpareParts = StoresSparePart.scoped_by_store_id(@currentStore.id)
    Rails.logger.debug { @currentStore.title }
    Rails.logger.debug { @storesSpareParts.count }
    render 'create.js'
  else
    render 'create.js'
  end
end
```

Here is the POST request passed to the create method:

```
Started POST "/stores_spare_parts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-02 17:52:00 +0200
Processing by StoresSparePartsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+NKTAC8ibgUW8vYg5H0XcWB+hAoFdw6on3Uw2XfP9WQ=", 
"stores_spare_part"=>{"spare_part_id"=>"6", "quantity"=>"2", 
"lowMark"=>"", "store_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Stores spare part"}
```

Comment: What params do you pass to your `url_for` call?

Comment: ... could you provide the full controller code within the actions in question? update_attributes_on_the_spot is really supposed to be a 'collection'? Could you describe it's purpose?

Comment: I just added the corresponding controller code. on_the_spot is a gem for inplace editing in views. I configured it according to the readme at: https://github.com/nathanvda/on_the_spot

Comment: Are you sure that the browser request is indeed a POST request?

Comment: Would it make the `url_for` lookup not working if it wasn't?

Comment: Can you include what parameters you are passing in your POST request to the create action?

Comment: Do you have any before-filters? Show their code? What does the `url_for` in the `create` method return? Can you debug the code (use rubymine).

Answer (score 1):

Change `post :update_attribute_on_the_spot` to `put :update_attribute_on_the_spot` since it looks like you are updating a record (put) and not creating a record (post).  I am pretty sure RoR got mad at me one time for doing something like what you did.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. It doesn't matter if I change or add the put line, I get the same error.

Comment: @Daniel regardless, it should be `put`... even the gem docs say to use `put`.  Its the way RESTful things work. Next, I would double check and make sure you put `gem "on_the_spot"` inside you gemfile and then ran `rails g on_the_spot:install` from the terminal.

Comment: What I didn't mention (because it was not my question), is that on_the_spot works in the index method. It only fails when calling the create method. I narrowed the error down to the url_for function. This is why I asked this question. The question about the actual on_the_spot problem is over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818361/problem-using-on-the-spot-gem-with-rails-3-and-newly-created-records/5826248#5826248

Comment: changing my post => put made my errors got away (this during a rails 3.0 => 3.1 port)